# Connecting to VirtualBox serial port for kernel debugging

Tags: serial-port, virtualbox

I'm trying to debug a boot time kernel panic of FreeBSD 14.0 i388 when booting in VirtualBox (host running FreeBSD 13.2 amd64).

In the past I did manage to capture output using a serial port connected to a raw file.

Now I'd like to have an interactive session to that I can use to get a backtrace from the kernel debugger.

There are things that I've tried

- Creating a pipe first with mkfifo and using "connect to existing pipe/socket". That just causes vbox to fail quickly.
- not creating a fifo and deselecting "connect to existing pipe/socket". When I do that FreeBSD starts printing messages to Video but very slowly (1 letter every few seconds)
- On the guest boot options has 4 options for the console: Video, Dual (serial primary), Dual (video primary) and Serial. Serial primary seems to work well with the raw dump.
- connecting to the created socket with cu

The real problem here is that I don't know what tool or the command to use to connect a terminal to the socket that vbox is creating.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, plain `telnet` does the job:

`telnet /tmp/vbox`

where /tmp/vbox is the pipe (or more precisely socket) created by VirtualBox.